# Managing Fields in an Entity based on a field in another Entity

Tags: javascript, tabs, entity, custom-fields

i wanna control a tab or directly fields in my Case entity based on a value of custom field in users entity.
i just wanna set disable the tab,-i dont want some users change this tab- if the field is empty in the user entity.

Ty for your help.

```
function disablefields(){
    Xrm.Page.getControl("customerid").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_siparisbelgeno").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_urunkodu").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_urunkodu2").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_adet").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_talep").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_zamanlama").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("incidentstagecode").setDisabled(true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("title").setDisabled(true); 
}
```

or a shortcut :

```
function hidetab(){
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("general").setVisible(false);
```

}

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: i have no code yet. i can write something for disabling fields in Case entity but i dont know how to tie up with the key field in users entity. im so new to java :)

Comment: I think perhaps you need to clarify your question a bit more - are you working with java or javascript? There is a difference. Also, you'll get more help if you have specific code you are struggling with - as it stands it's pretty difficult to figure out where to start helping you...

Comment: i see. then i share a code that sets disable the fields which i want and its working. im working with JavaScript. i wasnt know the difference so ty. i want to add a condition which controls the value of the field in users entity. For example if the value 'X' i let the user edit fields below. if its empty, i lock the fields as the code is doing.